# How to move the ticks of x axis (date in years) in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to check the boxplots for each year for variable `a` in the  `df data.frame`. I used the code below to create the `data.frame`

```
set.seed(123)
date <- as.Date(seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = 1), format="%Y-%m-%d")
a <- runif(9496, 3000, 120000)
df <- data.frame(date, a)
df[c(1:151,9313:9496), 2]<-NA
```

and using this code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=a, group=years(date)))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 year"),
               labels = date_format("%Y"))
```

I got this figure

[image]

The years on x axis are shown before and after the boxplot. How can I align the ticks of x axis and axis.text with the boxplots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the date breaks to be in the middle of each year:

```
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("1990-06-30"), as.Date("2015-06-30"), by="1 year"),
               labels = date_format("%Y"))
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the code again now with ggplot2_2.1.0. However, I got this error 

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "years"`

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Do you think it should be a separate question?

Comment: Are you sure that the `scale_x_date(...)` statement is what's causing the error?

Comment: No, I think it is `group=years(date)`

Comment: Did you mean the use the `year` function from the `lubridate` package?

Comment: Thanks. I loaded `lubridate` and the error message is not there anymore. However, there is only one boxplot for whole record https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrpq53rin5pac4o/Rplot.png?dl=0.

Comment: If you want to group by year, use the `year` function from lubridate (not `years`).

Comment: The grouping using `years` was working before, I wonder why it is not the case anymore